# Pivot columns and basic variables

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Suppose we are solving a system of linear equation and arrive at the following (augmented) matrix:

$ \begin{bmatrix}
 1& 6 &  0 & 3 & 0 & 0\\ 
 0& 0 &  1 & -4 & 0 & 5\\ 
 0& 0 &  0 & 0 & 1 & 7
\end{bmatrix} $

The question that arises is then: Which variables are basic and which are free? I know how to pick them up: You look for pivot and non-pivot columns. But what I wonder is: Why is it that non-pivot columns are those containing free variables and pivot columns are those containing the basic variables?

Answer (score 3):

You seem to draw your example from [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~dongwen/math2210s13/sec1_2.pdf). Now, in that example, it seems quite easy to reverse the roles, and have $x_1$, $x_3$, and $x_5$ as free variables. However, this is not always the case.

First, consider a regular system, for example

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
  & 4 & 5 \\
  &   & 6
\end{bmatrix}.$$

We cannot really choose anything here, right? We have $3$ pivot columns, and $3$ basic variables, while we have no non-pivot columns and no free variables.

Another example, where we do have some free variables, would be something like this:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
  &   &   & 6 & 7
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Obviously, we have only $2$ basic variables, and $3$ free ones. Pivot columns correspond to $x_1$, and $x_4$, which is $2$.

If you think about it, the number of pivot columns corresponds to the rank of the system, which is also the number of basic variables. Equivalently, the number of non-pivot columns corresponds to the number of free variables. That's why it makes sense to use that correspondence for a general rule, even though **sometimes** other choices would also do well.

Comment: I actually do not know what a rank of a matrix/system is (yet) since I very recently began my introductory course in linear algebra. Do you think could elaborate on that point? I.e. "# of pivot columns = rank of the system"?

Comment: [Rank of a matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_%28linear_algebra%29) equals the number of linearly independent rows/columns (the same number in both cases). In terms of linear equations, it's the number of linearly independent equations. When you get row echelon form (each row is either zeros only, or has strictly more leading zeroes than the one before it), rank is simply the number of non-zero rows, i.e., number of equations you didn't cancel.