# Number of variables, free and basic

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm slightly confused about how I can find how many variables I have if I start with a matrix.

So to start with I have the following matrix.

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    3 & 2 & 1 & 1 & -1 \\
    0 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 6 \\
    5 & 4 & 3 & 3 & -1 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

Through Gauss elimination I get this:

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 4 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

Is every column equal to a variable? And if yes in this case I have 5, with the 1rst, 2nd, and last being basic, and the other free. If not then how can I tell how many variables I have?

Comment: This one may be useful: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/497942/587192

Comment: @user587192 Yeah I read that while I was searching for an answer. However I still wasn't sure if the variables equal to the number of columns, since the answer doesn't state that anywhere and I don't want to assume that. I prefer to be sure :D

Comment: "Is every column *equal* to a variable?": A column in the matrix is a "vector" while a "variable" in a system of equations is a "scalar". They cannot be equal.

Comment: So how can I determine how many variables I have if I am not given an equation?

Comment: You are given the matrix (denote it as $A$). If you are solving an equation like $Ax=0$, then you have five variables since $A$ has five columns. (In this case, one may at most say "each column of the matrix *corresponds* to a variable"; "equal" is not a right word to use.) But if you are solving an equation $xA=0$, then there are four variables since $A$ has four rows.

Comment: Oh my I finally understand, thank you so much!!

Comment: In your case, you are right that $x_1,x_2,x_5$ are "basic" variables since they correspond to the pivot columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are given the matrix (denote it as $A$). If you are solving an equation like $Ax=0$, then you have five variables since $A$ has five columns. (In this case, one may at most say "each column of the matrix *corresponds* to a variable"; "equal" is not a right word to use.) But if you are solving an equation of the form $xA=0$, then there are four variables since $A$ has four rows.

Since you do Gaussian elimination on the *rows* of the matrix, you are solving equations in the form of $Ax=0$. So you are right that $x_1,x_2,x_5$ are "basic" variables since they correspond to the pivot columns.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely user587192 is correct but your matrix could also be interpreted as.
$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 1$
$3x_1 + 2x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 1$
$x_2 + 2x_3 + 2x_4 = 6$
$5x_1 + 4x_2 + 3x_3 + 3x_4 = -1$

More context is needed.

Comment: The matrix wasn't augmented, that's why I said 5 variables.